# Is command-line a meta tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I noticed that `command-line` had no tag-wiki. So I thought I might try to add one. Unfortunately I wasn't among the top 20 answerers in that tag so I couldn't do it.

I then thought about the `bash` tag(*). I think I could add the command-line tag to most (if not all) of the questions there without being wrong.

But the command-line tag also deals with the windows command line and there is no way to know the difference without the help of other tags.

So we have a tag that can't stand on it's own.

**Should we split it** to `command-line-win` and `command-line-nix` (Feel free to come up with better names)

Or should I just add the `command-line` tag to bash and other shell questions?

<sup>**(*)**</sup> where I can edit the tag-wiki

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Should we split it to command-line-win and command-line-nix `

Not really, IMO `[command-line]` should be left as it is.

> Or should I just add the command-line tag to bash and other shell questions?

That seems reasonable